# Google Places API for Android Place Picker Does not work

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am unable to use the Place picker in my app. The API worked then just stopped one day with no explanation.The picker shows up for a very short period of time then simply closes with no exception and nothing in the logs. The onActivityResult function is called with requestCode=1, resultCode=2(error code) and with no data. The sample code from google does the same thing. I have tried everything to get this working. anybody experience anything similar? Help please.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.easy.parcelapp."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <application
        android:name=".EasiParcelApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDEcV-My-Actual-API-Key-goes-here" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.easiparcel.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".JobListingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_listing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewJobActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_job"
            android:parentActivityName=".JobListingActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.easiparcel.JobListingActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewJobConfirmation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_job_confirmation"
            android:parentActivityName=".NewJobActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.easiparcel.NewJobActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".JobDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_job_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".JobListingActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.easiparcel.JobListingActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity.java

```
  public void HandleSenderAddressPickerClicked(View view)
{
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    LoadPlacePicker(PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

}

public void HandleRecieverAddressPickerClicked(View view)
{
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 2;
    LoadPlacePicker(PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

}

private void LoadPlacePicker(int PlacePickerRequest)
{
    try {

        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(NewJobActivity.this);
        // Start the Intent by requesting a result, identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, PlacePickerRequest);


    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), NewJobActivity.this, 0);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Toast.makeText(NewJobActivity.this, "Google Play Services is not available.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Sender Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Reciever
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Receiver Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

I figured out the answer to my own question.

If anybody else encounters the same issue, make sure you enable **"Places API for Android"** and not just **"Places API"** in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com). **"Places API for Android"** will not show up under "APIs & Auth/APIs" because it isnt a popular API (yet). You will have to search for it using the API search box.

Comment: This solved my problem too. But the strange thing is that I had this API enabled and 10 days ago place picker was working. But than it suddenly stopped working, and today when I entered to my developer console the API was disabled, but I haven't disabled it... It is strange..

Comment: it had the same quota before?  1,000 requests/day,  I don't remember

Comment: Working Perfectly

Comment: **Now its name is** `Places SDK for Android`

Answer (score 11):

instead of this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_key"/>
```

add this:

```
<meta-data            
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_key" />
```

It worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your build variant.

If you switched back from `release` to `debug`, you typically also get result code `2`.

Switching back to `release` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your account has not been deactivated in [Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)