# Unable to pick Place with Android Place Picker

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to use place picker in my app. By using this code I'm able to see Place Picker showing my current location on map but unable to select places.

```
 public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.location_task);
   }

  private static final int REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER = 1;

  public void onPickButtonClick(View v) {
           // Construct an intent for the place picker
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
            // Start the intent by requesting a result,
            // identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {

    }
  }
  @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER) {if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
}
```

[Here is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8IN5.png)

Comment: Could you give some more details on the issue you're seeing?  Is the Place Picker opening?  What happens when you select a place?

Comment: yes place picker opens but when i move marker i don't get any place to select @DanielResnick

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29762495/2692102) answer will help you tryit!.